# facing problem while nesting of member functions in c++

Tags: c++, c-strings

basically i just wanted to create a program which interchange a binary numbers after checking the number is binary.
i was watched tutorial 22 from youtube channel named code with harry and he did similar type of code and i thought i will do on my own something like him but yet something diffrent

this is the code i wrote

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

// A program to check binary number and interchange 0's and 1's 

class binarychange{
   string s;

   public:
       void read(void);
       void chk_bin(void);
       void change(void);
       void display(void);
};

void binarychange :: read(void){
    cout<<"enter a binary number"<<endl;
    cin>>s;
}

void binarychange :: chk_bin(void){
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        if(s.at(i)!='0' && s.at(i)!='1'){
            cout<<"Invalid binary format"<<endl;
        }
    }
        
}

void binarychange :: change(void){
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
       if (s.at(i)==0)
       {
           s.at(i)=1;
       }
       else{
           s.at(i)=0;
       }
    }
    
}

void binarychange :: display(void){
    cout<<"Displaying your binary number"<<endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        cout<<s.at(i);
    }
    cout<<endl;
}

int main(){
   binarychange b;
   b.read();
   b.chk_bin();
   b.display();
   b.change();
   b.display();



    return 0;
}
```

the output i got

```
enter a binary number
101
Displaying your binary number
101
Displaying your binary number
```

the output i want

```
enter a binary number
101
Displaying your binary number
101
Displaying your binary number
010
```

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but in both of those `for` loops you **know** that `i` is a valid index into the string, because you wrote it that way, so you don't need to check it with `s.at(i)`. Just use the index operator: `s[i]`.

Answer (score 2):

The value of `s.at(i)` is a character, not an integer number, so you should test for `s.at(i)=='0'`, rather than `s.at(i)==0` in the `binarychange :: change` method. Consequently, you should assign `'1'` or `'0'` instead of `1` or `0`, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

hey guys i got my answers, silly me just got hit by a small mistake

the correct code should be

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

// A program to check binary number and interchange 0's and 1's 

class binarychange{
   string s;

   public:
       void read(void);
       void chk_bin(void);
       void change(void);
       void display(void);
};

void binarychange :: read(void){
    cout<<"enter a binary number"<<endl;
    cin>>s;
}

void binarychange :: chk_bin(void){
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        if(s.at(i)!='0' && s.at(i)!='1'){
            cout<<"Invalid binary format"<<endl;
            exit(0);
        }
    }
        
}

void binarychange :: change(void){
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
       if (s.at(i)=='0')
       {
           s.at(i)='1';
       }
       else{
           s.at(i)='0';
       }
    }
    
}

void binarychange :: display(void){
    cout<<"Displaying your binary number"<<endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        cout<<s.at(i);
    }
    cout<<endl;
}

int main(){
   binarychange b;
   b.read();
   b.chk_bin();
   b.display();
   b.change();
   b.display();



    return 0;
}
```